# The splitting field of polynomial over $Z/2Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, splitting-field

I am trying to figure out the splitting field of $x^4 ＋ x^3 + 1$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$ .

I know $x^4 ＋ x^3 + 1$ over $\mathbb{F}_２$ is irreducible.

Let $α$ be a root of $x^4 ＋ x^3 + 1$, then the spitting field will be the field $\mathbb{F}_2(\alpha)$. So, the spitting field is isomorphic to finite field of $16$ elements.

> My question is:
>
> How to formally prove that the spitting field is the field
> $\mathbb{F}_2(\alpha)$

Let the other roots of $x^4＋x^3＋1$ be $\beta,\gamma,\delta$, I want to show $\mathbb{F}_2(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta)=$$\mathbb{F}_2(\alpha)$.

Why are $α^2, α^4,α^8$ also roots of $x^4＋x^3＋1$? Thank you for your help.

**After reading a lot of good comments,
could you someone write in answer form, the proof with normality and not using normality? Thank you.**

Comment: You tagged Galois-theory: Do you know/are you allowed to use that extensions of finite fields are normal?

Comment: yes, I admit that extension over finite field is Galois.

Comment: If you can't use @leolo1's suggestion, try to show that $\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^4,\alpha^8$ are distinct roots of the polynomial. More formally this means that the Galois group is generated by the Frobenius automorphism $\alpha\mapsto\alpha^p$ for extension $\mathbb F_p(\alpha)/\mathbb F_p$.

Comment: Sorry,but what does  ' use @leolo1's suggestion'  mean?

Comment: I just meant that if you don't have access to the fact that finite extensions of finite fields are normal, then you could have used my hint instead. But it doesn't matter, since you said you can use it.

Comment: The fact that finite extensions of finite fields are normal leads F2（α,β,γ,δ）＝F２（α）？Could you tell me the reason why?

Comment: As @Vercassivelaunos has told you, every root is a power of $\alpha$.

Comment: If $\mathbb F_2(\alpha)$ is normal, then the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ splits.

Comment: I'm confusing. Using 'normality' proof and 'not using normality' proof different?

Comment: Of course, the proofs would be different. A proof *not using normality* would revolve around proving that $\alpha$ is **any** root, then $\alpha^2$ is also a root. Of course, this also proves normality along the way while finding all the four roots :-)

Comment: Could you  tell me why α,α^2,α^4,α^8 are distinct roots? How to show this?（I know Frobenius generates Galois group of finite field extension）

Comment: $\alpha=\alpha^{2^m}$ if and only if $\alpha$ is an element of $\Bbb{F}_{2^m}$ if and only if the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is a factor of $m$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $a\in \Bbb{F}_{p^k}$ (some field with $p^k$ elements) let $$\prod_{m=0}^{k-1} (x-a^{p^m})=\sum_{n=0}^k c_m x^k$$
Because $b\to b^p$ is an automorphism and $a^{p^k}=a$ we get that $$\sum_{n=0}^k c_m^p x^k=\prod_{m=0}^{k-1} (x-(a^{p^m})^p)=\prod_{m=0}^{k-1} (x-a^{p^m})=\sum_{n=0}^k c_m x^k$$
Whence $c_m=c_m^p$ which implies that $c_m\in \Bbb{F}_p$ so that the minimal polynomial $f$ of $a$ divides $\sum_{n=0}^k c_m x^k$ which means that $f$ splits completely in $\Bbb{F}_p(a)$.